# What contentment and modesty, what persistence and grasping, toward what, craving, craving holding on what leads to liberation?

Tags: personal-practice, vipassana, abhidhamma, right-effort

What contentment and modesty, what persistence and grasping, toward what, craving, craving holding on what leads to liberation?

Doing, acting, content toward what is skilful, toward what unskilful in relation of path and fruit?

Doing, acting, persist toward what is skilful, toward what unskilful in relation of path and fruit?

*(Note: this is not given for exchange, stacks, trade or entertainment but as a means for liberation from this wheel.)*

Answer (score 1):

you discern and focus on the birth of stress and suffering,

```
The Buddha:

    If you ask me the coming-into-being of stress and suffering, I will tell it to you
    as one who discerns. From acquisition[1] as cause the many forms of stress and suffering come into being in the world. Whoever, unknowing, makes acquisitions
    -- the fool -- comes to stress and suffering
    again
    and again.

So one who's discerning,
    focused on the birth
    of stress and suffering,
    their coming-into-being, should make no acquisitions.
```

and the way to do that is

```
 Mettagu:


What we asked, you've expounded. Now we ask something else.
    Please tell us. How do the prudent cross over the flood of
    birth and aging,
    lamentation and sorrow? Please, sage, declare this to me
    as this Dhamma has
    been known by you.

The Buddha:

I will teach you the Dhamma
    -- in the here and now,
    not quoted words -- knowing which, living mindfully, you'll cross over beyond entanglement in the world.

Mettagu:

And I relish, Great Seer, that Dhamma     supreme, knowing which, living mindfully, I'll cross over beyond entanglement in the world.

The Buddha:

Whatever you're alert to,
    above, below,
    across, in between:[2] dispelling any delight,
        any laying claim
        to those things, consciousness should not take a stance
        in becoming. The monk who dwells thus
    -- mindful, heedful -- letting go of his sense of mine, knowing right here would abandon
        birth and aging,
    lamentation and sorrow,
        stress and suffering.
```

http://obo.genaud.net/dhamma-vinaya/ati/kd/snp/snp.5-04.than.ati.htm

Comment: So holding, persisting on discerning suffering and not content with any release, or how should this be regarded to fit to the question, good householder?